# Why when I put my component into <React.StrictMode> its constructor called twice?

Tags: reactjs

When I write

`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));`

the App's constructor is called once but when I write

`ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById("root"));`

the App's constructor is called twice. Why it is so and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React StrictMode intentionally call twice the constructor and others calls like render, componentShouldUpdate... That makes more deterministic the execution of the component and shows side efects of safe and unsafe functions like constructor, render, componentWillMount, componentWillUpdate

Note: Like as document say, this double call only works in dev mode, in production env should works like React.Fragment

Check more about this [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)