# Why does empty App component calls render() and componentDidMount() twice?

Tags: reactjs

I have basic App component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('didMount')
  }

  render() {
   console.log('render')
   return <p>Empty component</p>
  }
}
```

The project is also empty. There is nothing else in this file.
Console output every reloading:

```
render
render
didMount
didMount
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Are you rendering `<StrictMode>` around the `<App>`? https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: @NicholasTower yeah. Removing this helped.

Comment: Removing it will change the logging, but i recommend you keep it in. It's there to help you catch problems. The double rendering only happens in development builds, not production builds.

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing `<React.StrictMode>` in index.js helped.

More details on how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524060/15622812